# Low-down vs lowdown as noun vs adjective

Tags: spelling, word-meaning

In an online CPE mock test I was given this question:

- The princess's nanny's autobiography really gives the ____ on the life among the royals.

The correct answer was "**low-down**" which I did choose.

But I'm having a trouble understanding why an "*adjective-spelled*" word is used in place of a noun.

I might be wrong, but "*low-down*" is an adjective that means: **mean or unfair** whereas "*lowdown*" is the noun that means: **relevant information**.

Is there no difference between spelling this word with a hyphen or without one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lowdown%20on%2C%20low-down%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clowdown%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clow%20-%20down%20on%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clowdown%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clow%20-%20down%20on%3B%2Cc1), it seems that there is some variation in the spelling of the noun form. While it is true that the majority of usages are unhyphenated, currently about 15% of instances are hyphenated.

The word only came into use in 1920 and, between then and 1960, both spellings were in equal use. I guess that it was first put into a dictionary at that point, and from then on the dictionary (unhyphenated) form has grown progressively stronger.

Hyphenation is generally regarded as a form of punctuation, and as such there is a lot more flexibility than there is with the actual letters in a word.

Comment: +1 for the down-and-dirty on **low-down**.